# PHP algorithm problems to do bulls and cows game

Tags: php, algorithm

I have problems with bulls and cows game. Problem is, I do not know how to do to make cows and bulls. I tried by all means, but I can not figure out how to do it.
I have written code to generate numbers like this:

Code: http://ilinden2012.com/t/in.txt

Demo: http://ilinden2012.com/t/in.php

Can someone help me?

Comment: For anyone else unfamiliar with the game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows

Comment: It looked, but does not help me ...

Comment: I know, but your question is not really readable when one is unaware of the game. Hence the link. Furthermore, you'll really need to be a bit more specific to get help. Simply stating that 'it does not work' is not going to cut it.